# How to run a function with empty main() method in C?

Tags: c++, c, program-entry-point

This approach works in `C++`, but it doesn't work in `C`

It gives me this error `initializer element is not constant`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int n = printf("Hello World");

int main() {}
```

How can I print `hello world` with an empty `main` function?

I just need to convert this `C++` code into `C`

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int n = printf("Hello World");

int main() {}
```

or this

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 1;
}

int x = fun();

int main() {}
```

or this C++ code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int fun()
{
    cout << "Hello World";
    return 1;
}

int x = fun();

int main() {}
```

Comment: In C variable initializers needs to be compile-time constants. Function calls happen at run-time so their results can't be compile-time constants.

Comment: As for what you're trying to do, ***why*** are you trying to do it? Is there a real and underlying problem that you need to solve, or is it just plain curiosity? If it's curiosity then please add a note about that in your question, otherwise please ask directly about the actual problem you need to solve.

Comment: Also, C and C++ are very different languages, despite some shared syntax and common roots. The two languages have very different rules for many things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With no `main()` is quite possible, but involves redefining the `_start()` function.

```
/*main.c*/

#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h>

void _start() 
{  
    printf("No main function!\n");
    exit(0); 
}
```

compile with:

For Windows(10, gcc 8.1.0) and Ubuntu(18.04, gcc 9.2.0)

```
gcc main.c -nostartfiles
```

For MacOS (10.14.6, Xcode 11.3)

```
clang -Wl,-e,-Wl,__start main.c
```

More info about Linux program start [Linux x86 Program Start Up](http://dbp-consulting.com/tutorials/debugging/linuxProgramStartup.html)

Answer (score 1):

> How to run a function with empty main method in C?

#### Short answer

It's impossible in any way that is suitable for production code.

#### Long answer

It's possible, but involves a lot of trickery, like redefining where the program should start it's execution. It cannot be done in a standard way. C simply does not allow other things than declarations and initializations outside functions.

A related thing is that it is possible to declare main as something else than a function. Here is an article about writing a program that prints "Hello World!" while declaring main as an array instead of a function. http://jroweboy.github.io/c/asm/2015/01/26/when-is-main-not-a-function.html

And that's probably the level of trickery you would need to use.